# Regular expression for data between specific number of occurrences of underscore

Tags: regex

I want to extract data between only the specific occurrence of _(2 in my case)

Can you help me write a regex which will match the below sample input and output?

Sample Input                   ==> Sample Output

App1                           ==>  App1

App1_app2                     ==>  App1_app2

App1_app2_app3               ==>  App1_app2_app3

App1_app2_app3_app4           ==> App1_app2_app3

App1_app2_app3_app4_app5       ==>  App1_app2_app3

Comment: You need to show us what you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

This Regex match your sample:

```
^[^\s_]+(_[^\s_]+)?(_[^\s_]+)?
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/fHBeou/1/

Notice that you must apply global and multi line modifiers to this regex works.